# Scroll Wheel Button Action appearing on its own, Dell Laptops

Tags: dell-precision

I have about 5 Dell Precision Laptops that are all experiencing the same problem. The action that occurs when you press in the mouse wheel, the two arrows that allow you to use the movement of the mouse to scroll as apposed to the actual scroll wheel, is firing on it's own. I have tried re-installing drivers, I have tried disabling the at function so only the left and right mouse buttons work, but nothing has come up. Google searches have not proved fruitful either. They are all using docks, and it occurs if plugged in to the laptop or the dock. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What make/model is the mouse?

Comment: What you're describing is a default feature of Internet Explorer, Microsoft Office, iTunes, and several other browsers.  Is this happening in all applications?

Comment: You're getting the scroll arrow thing when you DON'T click the middle button?

Comment: @Chris - Any Mouse

Comment: @Hand-E-Food - yes, all applications, this is a default feature of any program with a window

Comment: @techie007 - yes, it is occurring without pressing the button, it occurs when the button is disabled